# Vue Computed Property not updating. Very strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Yes, it's another 'Vue computed property is not updating question...

Below is an excerpt of my component with the issue. I have a computed property 'fieldModel' this uses Vue.set to set a new value, then i console log that computed property immediately after assigning it a new value the javascript object updates and is viewable in devtools, the computed property however has not updated, and neither has the DOM.

```js
export default {
    props:{
        value:{
            type:Object,
            required:true,
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            model:this.value,
            key:'something',
        }
    },
    created() {

        var self = this;

        setTimeout(function() {
            self.fieldModel = 'Apples';
        }, 1000);
    },
    computed:{
        fieldModel:{
            get() {
                return this.model[this.key];
            },
            set(value) {

                var self = this;

                self.$set(self.model, self.key, value);
                console.log(self.model[self.key], self.fieldModel);
                //Logs out 'Apples', undefined, 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Can't replicate](https://jsfiddle.net/4b8mf5zk/).

Comment: @StevenB. Not enough information provided or the above code does not replicate the issue for you?

Comment: The above code does not replicate the issue as can be seen in that linked fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example code i posted in the original question works correctly, This lead me to break down my code and resolve my issue.

I had this component in a v-for loop with recursive nesting, Another component appeared to mutate the v-model object without updating these components resulting in some very strange behaviour.

I was able to solve the problem by adding a watcher for 'value' to update the model field and a watcher for 'model' to $emit('input') any changes to the model to it's parent.

This results in an infinite loop that crashes the browser, however i was able to resolve that by adding a check to see if the model/value is the same object

Example code is simplified for brevity:

```js
{
   watch:{
      value(newValue) {
         if(this.model != newValue) {
            this.model = newValue;
         }
      },
      model(newModel) {
         this.$emit('input', newModel)
      },
   }
}
```